# Ruby on Rails - error when running cucumber: You have already activated activesupport 3.2.1, but your Gemfile requires activesupport 3.1.0. 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, rvm

I know this question has been asked in one form or the another before, but I still can't get a working solution for this.

I'm taking the saas course offered online and the code is directly cloned from 
https://github.com/saasbook/hw3_rottenpotatoes

When I run cucumber from the command prompt

```
Using the default profile...
You have already activated activesupport 3.2.1, but your Gemfile requires activesupport 3.1.0. Using bundle exec may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `block in setup'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:17:in `setup'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:110:in `setup'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `rescue in require'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
/Users/chemin/rails_projects/saas/hw3_rottenpotatoes/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/chemin/rails_projects/saas/hw3_rottenpotatoes/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/chemin/rails_projects/saas/hw3_rottenpotatoes/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/cucumber-rails-1.3.0/lib/cucumber/rails.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `rescue in require'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
/Users/chemin/rails_projects/saas/hw3_rottenpotatoes/features/support/env.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:129:in `load'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:129:in `load_code_file'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:171:in `load_file'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:175:in `load_step_definitions'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:40:in `run!'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/bin/cucumber:14:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/bin/cucumber:19:in `load'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/bin/cucumber:19:in `<main>'
```

after running bundle install version I get an even uglier message

```
Could not find rack-cache (~> 1.1) amongst [actionmailer-3.1.0, actionpack-3.1.0, activemodel-3.1.0, activerecord-3.1.0, activeresource-3.1.0, activesupport-3.1.0, addressable-2.2.7, archive-tar-minitar-0.5.2, arel-2.2.1, bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1, builder-3.0.0, capybara-1.1.2, childprocess-0.3.1, coffee-rails-3.1.1, coffee-script-2.2.0, coffee-script-source-1.2.0, columnize-0.3.6, cucumber-1.1.8, cucumber-rails-1.3.0, cucumber-rails-training-wheels-1.0.0, database_cleaner-0.7.1, diff-lcs-1.1.3, erubis-2.7.0, execjs-1.3.0, ffi-1.0.11, gherkin-2.8.0, haml-3.1.4, hike-1.2.1, i18n-0.6.0, jquery-rails-1.0.19, json-1.6.5, json_pure-1.6.5, launchy-2.0.5, libv8-3.3.10.4-x86_64-darwin-10, linecache19-0.5.12, mail-2.3.0, mime-types-1.17.2, multi_json-1.1.0, nokogiri-1.5.0, polyglot-0.3.3, rack-1.3.6, rack-cache-1.0.3, rack-mount-0.8.3, rack-ssl-1.3.2, rack-test-0.6.1, rails-3.1.0, railties-3.1.0, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.12, ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25, ruby-debug19-0.11.6, ruby_core_source-0.1.5, rubyzip-0.9.6.1, sass-3.1.15, sass-rails-3.1.5, selenium-webdriver-2.13.0, sprockets-2.0.3, sqlite3-1.3.5, term-ansicolor-1.0.7, therubyracer-0.9.10, thor-0.14.6, tilt-1.3.3, treetop-1.4.10, tzinfo-0.3.31, uglifier-1.2.3, xpath-0.1.4] (Gem::LoadError)
/Users/chemin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:451:in `block in find_in_unresolved'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:451:in `map'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:451:in `find_in_unresolved'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:43:in `require'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:17:in `build'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:138:in `definition'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:126:in `load'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:110:in `setup'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `rescue in require' 
/Users/chemin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
/Users/chemin/rails_projects/saas/hw3_rottenpotatoes/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/chemin/rails_projects/saas/hw3_rottenpotatoes/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/chemin/rails_projects/saas/hw3_rottenpotatoes/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/cucumber-rails-1.3.0/lib/cucumber/rails.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `rescue in require'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
/Users/chemin/rails_projects/saas/hw3_rottenpotatoes/features/support/env.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:129:in `load'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:129:in `load_code_file'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:171:in `load_file'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:175:in `load_step_definitions'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:40:in `run!'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/bin/cucumber:14:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/bin/cucumber:19:in `load'
/Users/chemin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/bin/cucumber:19:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There's a couple solutions, the easiest of which would be to try running `bundle exec cucumber` first, and see if that solves your problem.

If that doesn't work, delete your rails3tutorial gemset and re-create it again:

```
rvm gemset delete rails3tutorial
rvm 1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial --create
```

Then run `bundle`, and hopefully it will install your gems for you.  Follow this up with `bundle exec cucumber`  (I almost always run my specs and cukes using `bundle exec` so that it doesn't try accidentally loading stale gems).

Hopefully this works!

UPDATE:  Explaining `bundle exec` a little more

`bundle exec` is a command that bundler comes with that will run any other command in the context of your Gemfile.  In this case, you're essentially telling it to run the `cucumber` command but *only* with the gems from your Gemfile, and not with all the gems currently available.

For instance, if you have previously installed `activesupport 3.2.1`, and your Gemfile asks for `activesupport 3.1.0`.  When this happens I believe the cucumber command itself pulls in 'activesupport' (maybe via the `require 'cucumber/rails'` call in env.rb) which grabs any random version of activesupport it can (let's say it grabs 3.2.1) from your available gems.  After this, it decides to load up your rails environment to start running your features.  When it starts loading your actual app, the code looks at your Gemfile.lock and sees that what you actually want is `activesupport 3.1.0`, but it can't load an old version on top of a new version, so it crashes with the error James Lin pasted.

This is why, if you're using rvm, it's a good idea to keep separate gemsets for your separate projects, and delete/re-create the gemsets if you're updating your gems on that project so you don't keep old versions of gems around.  Alternatively, `bundle exec` tends to solve 99% of the problems as well.  If you aren't using rvm, and have multiple projects, then you probably have many different versions of many different gems, and you should always use `bundle exec` to do things like execute rake tasks, run cucumer features and other unit tests, etc.

Comment: Can you explain what is the difference between "cucumber" and "bundle exec cucumber"?

Comment: @coelhudo I put the explanation at the end of my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Or you could do `bundle update` to make sure all your gem plugins are the newest version and it will update your `Gemfile.lock`, so those two will be consistent.

I guess the difference between `bundle exec` and `bundle update` is whether you want bundle provide the version your app asking for or update your app gemfile so that the app wouldn't insist a stale version of gem when newer version installed and cause problem because the gem file.

Because when a version conflict happens, it is generally a good idea to make sure what installed in you system environment consistent with your app `Gemfile` or lock file as you don't want them trying to use an old version of gem when newer version available, unless you want freeze your gem system using rvm or similar at app level, but again, when you distribute you ruby app, it may cause problem in other machines.

In the end, because the need to distribute your app, unless newer version of gem file doesn't working with existing app, I think it shouldn't insist on an stale known-working version, unless you always want keep it on the safe side which is a valid argument.